# Using NSFetchedResultsController to fetch an object's property

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I need to make a CoreData fetch request that grabs a ManagedObject of type "List" which properties include: name(String), hitCount(Int), lastUpdated(Date) and contents(OrderedSet). Now I need to populate my TableView with the "Media" ManagedObjects within the contents property of the List Object. When I already have an instance of the List who's contents I want I've tried...

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Media>(entityName: "Media")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF in %@", list.contents)
```

...which gives me what is already in CoreData, but not any NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate updates on additional objects obtained through network calls and added to the database after my initial grab. I also tried...

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Media>(entityName: "List")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", list.name)
```

...which returns the List item and I will get NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate updates, but only of type move on the List object itself - not the actual changes needed to apply to the TableView (delete/insert,etc) when it's content property changes. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an inverse relationship from Media to List?  If so, is it to-one or to-many: can a Media object be related to more than one List?  (The predicate you require is different in each case).

Comment: Yes, there is an inverse relationship. The contents property of the List object maps to a Media object is a to-many type. As of now the inverse relationship from a Media object to a List object is a to-one type, but thinking about it now a Media object can exist in multiple lists, so maybe both sides should be a to-many type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inverse relationship is to-one, called `listRelationship`, then you can use:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Media>(entityName: "Media")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "listRelationship == %@", list)
```

as the fetch underlying the FetchedResultsController.  If the relationship is to-many, change the predicate to "ANY listRelationship == %@".  In either case, it will be difficult to ensure the sort order used by the FRC matches the NSOrderedSet in the `List` object.

If that is important to you, you will need to explicitly model the sort order with an index attribute.  If the relationship is to-one, you can add the `index` attribute to the `Media` entity, but if it is to-many, life gets more difficult: a `Media` object might be the first item in one List, but the last item in another List - so the index relates to a particular List and a particular Media item.  In that case, add another entity, "ListEntry", with an `index` attribute and to-one relationships to `List` and `Media` (each with to-many inverses).